# Split string just after space

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

In Python 3.x, how would I split a string like this:

```
foo bar hello world
```

So the output would be a list like:

```
['foo ', 'bar ', 'hello ', 'world ']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just split at whitespaces and then add them back again.

```
a = 'foo bar hello world'

splitted = a.split()  # split at ' '

splitted = [x + ' ' for x in splitted]  # add the ' ' at the end
```

Or if you want it a bit more fancy:

```
splitted = ['{} '.format(item) for item in a.split()]
```

Comment: Will this work with multiple spaces as well, i.e., inserting back the correct amount?

Comment: That makes it ambiguous where the string should be splitted. After the first, second, last? Given that he didn't specify this information (and I didn't thought about it given the example) I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @RadLexus: No, it won't. It's not possible to preserve arbitrary whitespace with simple use of plain string methods like this.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to handle and preserve arbitrary runs of whitespace, you'll need a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|\S+)\s*', '   foo \tbar    hello world')
['   ', 'foo \t', 'bar    ', 'hello ', 'world']
```

Comment: This is useful and I'll keep this solution in mind, but I don't need to keep extra whitespace.